# IIS outbound rule to change text within <span>

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

We are currently using URL rewrites to replace images and links. But we would like to replace some text contained within a  tag. Has anyone achieved this before?

I did try to add a custom tag

```
            <customTags>
                <tags name="span">
                    <tag name="span" attribute="" />
                </tags>
            </customTags>
```

But wasn't sure what to add as the attribute if its just the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, as IIS URL Rewrite is only designed for URL rewrite.

If you do want to post-process requests, write a HttpModule or IIS module, and hook to the relevant events,

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview